# html div, css design overlapping when on click home page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css

when home page show, about part show on slide part about .30 second. but when about html code set where about view its ok. this page add under layout page. main css add layout , here just  slider+about view page code add. it's asp.net MVC project.

```
 <!-- Slider -->
    <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="~/Content/public_content/img/slides/1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h3>HEART SPECIALIST</h3>
                    <p>Doloribus omnis minus temporibus perferquam</p>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Content/public_content/img/slides/2.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h3>BETTER CARE</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolo amet, consectetur  provident.</p>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<!-- About-->

    <section id="call-to-action-2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                    <h3>Welcome to MEDICO Hospitals</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores quae porro consequatur aliquam, incidunt eius magni provident, doloribus omnis minus temporibus perferendis nesciunt quam repellendus nulla nemo ipsum odit corrupti</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or css you could include?

Comment: yes, jsfiddle or css file include